# Trix editor How comes that the toolbar disappear on editor blur?

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, trix

I try to use trix editor in Laravel8 livewire. I could manage to have it working but there is one point that is very annoying.
I use a trix livewire component that is inserted in a Post component.
I is suggested to use the trix-blur event to save the content of the editor. This works perfectly and I can use a store button to have the value of the trix editor component saved in the post record in the database.
The annoying point is that when the trix-blur event occurs, **the tool bar disappears and never shows up again** even if the editor regains the focus. Thus the user cannot use it any longer.
What can I do to prevent this behavior.

here is the trix component

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;

class Trix extends Component
{

    public $value;
    public $trixId;
    const EVENT_VALUE_UPDATED = 'trix_value_updated';

    public function mount($value = ''){
        $this->value = $value;
        $this->trixId = 'trix-' . uniqid();
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.trix');
    }
    public function updatedValue($value){
     $this->emit(self::EVENT_VALUE_UPDATED, $this->value);
}
}
```

and its view

```
<div>

    <input id="{{ $trixId }}" type="hidden" name="content" value="{{ $value }}">
    <trix-editor wire:ignore class="text-white" input="{{ $trixId }}"></trix-editor>

</div>
<script>
    var trixEditor = document.getElementById("{{ $trixId }}")

    addEventListener("trix-blur", function(event) {
        @this.set('value', trixEditor.getAttribute('value'))
    })
  
</script>
```

and here is related part of the post view

```
<div>

    <div class="button-line flex flex-row">
        <span class="flex w-full rounded-md shadow-sm sm:ml-3 sm:w-auto">
            <button  wire:click.prevent="store()" id="submit" type="button" class="button-register">
                Enregistrer l'info-lettre
            </button>
        </span>
        <span class="mt-3 flex w-full rounded-md shadow-sm sm:mt-0 sm:w-auto">
            <button  wire:click="closeModalPopover()" type="button" class="button-cancel">
                Abandonner
            </button>
        </span>
    </div>
@livewire('trix',['value'=>$body])

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found an answer here
https://devdojo.com/tnylea/laravel-livewire-trix-editor-component

The answer is at the end in the Bonus part. Note only the trix editor input must have a wire:ignore but also the div that surrounds it

```
<div wire:ignore>

    <input id="{{ $trixId }}" type="hidden" name="content" value="{{ $value }}">
    <trix-editor wire:ignore class="text-white" input="{{ $trixId }}"></trix-editor>

</div>
```